# How to find just the first character or value of a MD5 hash string

Tags: encryption, hash, decryption, md5, string

I want to know how to find just the first character or digit in first part of a 64 length string from a MD5 hash. For example, we have a hash:

`f95debd50b95304af9de1975393069143b7fb7df10ea00d189657d55b89c555c`

and MD5 is:

`be254c231d70885f6db16c0399be3066`

In this case, what is the solution to find "f" that is the first part of string from the MD5?

Comment: That's not how hashes work, you can't get parts of it at a time

Answer (score 6):

The MD5 pre-image resistance theoretically is broken bu not practically. Instead of the generic preimage attack with 2<sup>128</sup> complexity, there is an [attack that requires 2<sup>123.4</sup> complexity](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_8). MD5, however, is not practically broken. You cannot reach the 123-bit search space in a meaningful time. Consider the collective power of BitCoin miners; in 2020/1/17 they [reached 126.1314 Exahashes per second,](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html) that makes

- 2<sup>67</sup> SHA256 double hashes in a second, and
- 2<sup>92</sup> SHA256 double hashes in a year. So you need 2<sup>21</sup> years with that power.

What you asking is against the design principle of the hash functions; the avalanche criteria. That is changing one bit of input will flip approximately half of the output bits, randomly.

If you can find even a single bit better than the generic pre-image attack, then you have a theoretical weakness. you can use this attack like divide and conquer technique to reduce the overall pre-image attack complexity.