# Is MD5 hashing possible by divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: hash, md5, algorithm

I would like to compute the MD5 hash of a file

The file is uploaded to my webserver by my clients
The file is uploaded in pieces (called chunks)
The client also sends the md5 hash of the file so that the file integrity could be verified

The chunks can come in any random order. (The first chunk doesn't always have to come first)
My web server stores the chunks in persistence storage.

**Is it possible for me to compute the hash (or any digest) of the individual chunks and arrive at the hash of the file?**

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: (It's a explained in the original description)
My application (multiple instance) gets the files chunk by chunk, and I am storing the file as chunks in a storage.
I need to verify the integrity by hash

Comment: That explains *what* you want to do, but not *why*. Why not use MD5 over the whole file?

Comment: oh okay... I wish i don't need to do this. The system is implemented already and now we pulling all chunks and we are computing MD5. Planning to change the implementation to it more intelligently without breaking the contact

Comment: Might be worth a mention that if you are using HTTPS then integrity checking is not really necessary at all - HTTPS already has that built in.

Comment: @ConorMancone: HTTPS only prevents corruption of data in transit.  Hashes, used properly, can also guard against other problems such as having a file change between the time one group of chunks is requested and the time another groups of chunks is requested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The classical solution is using the [Merkle-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). To use the Merkle-Tree for uploading, the client forms the Merkle-Tree and calculates the hashes, and sends you the root hash in advance in a secure channel with a digital signature.

In the Merkle Tree, the data (chunk) can arrive at the server in random order with the sibling hashes of the path from the data to the root. The server can use the root hash and the data and sibling hashes to check that the data is valid.

This will increase the bandwidth with `O(log n)` where `n` is the number of parts. With MD5 it will be `128*log n` ( The `log n` is used for the height of the tree).

For example for a `1GB` file, with each part is `1MB` and using a `32B` Hash function, like SHA256, for this the client needs to store 64KB hash values and for sending a `1MB` chunk with a 320KB hash data will be transmitted and the overhead of the transfer will be `0.031%`

The cost of verifying for each chunk will be `O(log n)`, and remember the Cryptographic hash functions are very fast.

and don't use MD5 it is [no longer considered to be secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/225227/86735) Cryptographic hash function, rather prefer at least SHA256 or use the [Blake2](https://www.blake2.net/) which has speed records. There are also parallel hashes like [ParallelHash](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-185) of SHA3 and the [Blake3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)#BLAKE3). This can fasten the calculations whenever the parallelization provides benefits.

For a nice and comprehensive guide to  how the Merkle-Tree works see Squeamish Ossifrage' [answer on Cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71313/18298)

Comment: Got it... So a simple hash is not going to work in my case. But to make this work I need to implement Merkle tree that will change the contract that is existing between the server and the client

Comment: @NachiappanKumarappan Merkle Trees are in some sense optimal. We can design a sequential very easily (here with [GCM with detection additions, deletions, and in the final part the truncation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86081/18298)).  Since you requested that data can arrive in random order, the direct solution is the Merkle Tree. One can design a linear approach, however, that will not as simple as Merkle Tree and satisfying the integrity will be harder.

Comment: yeah... I definitely want to be solving business problems... Solving this seems to be expensive affair (A project in its own right)

Comment: While it is accurate that MD5 is no longer secure, that doesn't mean MD5 is useless for the purpose of file verification or other non-secure applications.  When your purpose is trying to verify the transmitted data between two trusted parties, there's nothing wrong with using MD5.

Comment: @Nick2253, if you don't trust the connection between those two trusted parties, and you need to worry about someone in the middle trying to engineer a collision (to let them replace the document without the hash appearing to change)... that assertion is problematic.

Comment: @Nick2253, ...indeed, I'm curious about exactly which kind of attack profile it is for which you're asserting that md5 is still a suitable defense.

Comment: @Nick2253 the security need is defined according to your threat. On the Cryptographic side, we usually consider the adversary capabilities only computationally bounded with any technique they can apply old or new.  I never suggest using MD5, collision easy, pre-image is faster than brute-force. While there are secure alternatives faster than MD5 like the Blake2b why use MD5 at all? What happened to the active adversary that can replace the MD5 hash of a package with a secondary image? If you only consider some errors on the path, then an error-correcting code can be faster than all.

Comment: @NachiappanKumarappan: If you're going to change the contract AND if you don't care about hash security (as implied by your choice of MD5), you could just have the uploader send the CRC of each chunk as the chunks are uploaded. This also means you can detect failed chunks, rather than needing to see the entire file to detect failure.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Using MD5, it is possible to construct a *pair* of files, one benign and one malicious, which have the same hash, *if one has allowed to freely choose part of the content of both*.  There are some usage scenarios where this would be a major danger, and others where it would not.  Handling all scenarios with a hash scheme which is suitable for all scenarios is often better than handling some with a scheme that's suitable only for them, and handling others with a scheme that could have been used for all scenarios.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, MD5, as far as anyone knows, is still preimage resistant.  It's completely broken for situations where the attacker can freely choose *every* file being hashed (such as when getting a third party to sign a file), but in situations where at least one file is not under the attacker's control, there are no known attacks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not asserting anything about MD5 being a suitable defense for any "attack profile".  I'm merely suggesting that dismissing MD5 for the purpose of data integrity checking is throwing the baby out with the bath water.  Tools abound for calculating the MD5 hash, and functions are built into many programming languages.  An MD5 hash is relatively efficient to calculate, and an MD5 hash is short enough to be checked manually.  Assuming an otherwise secure transport mechanism (like TLS), you're only trying to protect yourself from data corruption (etc.)